# Linked.In authentication in Windows App

Tags: c#, linkedin-api, windows

Can anybody help me to find some nice resources for integrating linkedin authentication on windows app development ? Any links, source codes, video tutorial links , youtube links would also be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample code from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/LinkedIn-OAuth-20-Example-408dd568 :

```
private async Task getAuthorizeCode() 
{ 
    var url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code" 
                                    + "&client_id=" + _consumerKey 
                                    + "&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_scope) 
                                    + "&state=STATE" 
                                    + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_callbackUrl); 
    log(url); 
    var startUri = new Uri(url); 
    var endUri = new Uri(_callbackUrl); 

    WebAuthenticationResult war = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync( 
                                                WebAuthenticationOptions.None, 
                                                startUri, 
                                                endUri); 
    switch (war.ResponseStatus) 
    { 
        case WebAuthenticationStatus.Success: 
            { 
                // grab access_token and oauth_verifier 
                var response = war.ResponseData; 
                IDictionary<string, string> keyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
                var qSplit = response.Split('?'); 
                foreach (var kvp in qSplit[qSplit.Length - 1].Split('&')) 
                { 
                    var kvpSplit = kvp.Split('='); 
                    if (kvpSplit.Length == 2) 
                    { 
                        keyDictionary.Add(kvpSplit[0], kvpSplit[1]); 
                    } 
                } 

                _authorizationCode = keyDictionary["code"]; 
                break; 
            } 
        case WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel: 
            { 
                log("HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + war.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString()); 
                break; 
            } 
        default: 
        case WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp: 
            log("Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + war.ResponseStatus.ToString()); 
            break; 
    } 
}
```